# Regex works in JavaScript but not in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex that I use to validate emails and in JavaScript it looks like this:

```
function CheckIfValidEmail(TheEmail) {

    return /^([^\x00-\x20\x22\x28\x29\x2c\x2e\x3a-\x3c\x3e\x40\x5b-\x5d\x7f-\xff]+|\x22([^\x0d\x22\x5c\x80-\xff]|\x5c[\x00-\x7f])*\x22)(\x2e([^\x00-\x20\x22\x28\x29\x2c\x2e\x3a-\x3c\x3e\x40\x5b-\x5d\x7f-\xff]+|\x22([^\x0d\x22\x5c\x80-\xff]|\x5c[\x00-\x7f])*\x22))*\x40([^\x00-\x20\x22\x28\x29\x2c\x2e\x3a-\x3c\x3e\x40\x5b-\x5d\x7f-\xff]+|\x5b([^\x0d\x5b-\x5d\x80-\xff]|\x5c[\x00-\x7f])*\x5d)(\x2e([^\x00-\x20\x22\x28\x29\x2c\x2e\x3a-\x3c\x3e\x40\x5b-\x5d\x7f-\xff]+|\x5b([^\x0d\x5b-\x5d\x80-\xff]|\x5c[\x00-\x7f])*\x5d))*$/.test(TheEmail);
}
```

I didn't create that regex, I found it online. I want to use the same regex in my C# code with an extension method like this:

```
public static bool IsValidEmailAddress(this string TentativeEmailAddress)
{
    string Pattern = "@/^([^\x00-\x20\x22\x28\x29\x2c\x2e\x3a-\x3c\x3e\x40\x5b-\x5d\x7f-\xff]+|\x22([^\x0d\x22\x5c\x80-\xff]|\x5c[\x00-\x7f])*\x22)(\x2e([^\x00-\x20\x22\x28\x29\x2c\x2e\x3a-\x3c\x3e\x40\x5b-\x5d\x7f-\xff]+|\x22([^\x0d\x22\x5c\x80-\xff]|\x5c[\x00-\x7f])*\x22))*\x40([^\x00-\x20\x22\x28\x29\x2c\x2e\x3a-\x3c\x3e\x40\x5b-\x5d\x7f-\xff]+|\x5b([^\x0d\x5b-\x5d\x80-\xff]|\x5c[\x00-\x7f])*\x5d)(\x2e([^\x00-\x20\x22\x28\x29\x2c\x2e\x3a-\x3c\x3e\x40\x5b-\x5d\x7f-\xff]+|\x5b([^\x0d\x5b-\x5d\x80-\xff]|\x5c[\x00-\x7f])*\x5d))*$/";
    Regex regex = new Regex(Pattern);
    
    return regex.IsMatch(TentativeEmailAddress.ToLower());
}
```

Basically, I copy-paste the regex in the C# code expecting it to work but instead I get an error message that says `parsing 'the regex' - Too many )'s.`

What do I need to change to make this work?

Comment: holy sweet lord. let me suggest you try something like this: http://composableregex.apphb.com/ to help you break this kind of thing up. full disclosure, it's a site i wrote to build composable regex and help manage that.

Comment: I know I'll need a new pair of glasses, that regex broke mine ;-)

Comment: @devshorts: is your site still available? That link doesn't work for me.

Comment: @halfer its not but the github is https://github.com/devshorts/ComposableRegex

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you misplaced `@` which should be before `"` in C# so that you don't have to double backslashes. Also, you don't need to put regex in `/ ... /`

```
string Pattern = @"^ ... $";
```