# Capture full delimiter with regex

Tags: regex

I've been attempting to learn enough RegEx today to split the following string into the format below:

> **Original string:** foo u:james h c:user p:product
>
> **Desired output:** ["foo", "u:", "james h", "c:", "user", "p:", "product"]
>
> **Actual output:** ["foo ", "u", "james h ", "c", "user ", "p", "product"]

The actual output is just missing the colon. It also has trailing spaces, but I can fix that with c# if I can get the full delimiter.

It *feels* like I'm very close, but I'll confess that the RegEx above required most of my evening. What am I missing?

Here's my RegEx so far:

```
([a-z]):+
```

Comment: What language do you use? c#?

Comment: @Psidom, sorry, just realized that I forgot the RegEx. I'm testing in a jsFiddle, but the end result will be c#.

Comment: So it's in javascript?

Comment: @Psidom, yes. https://jsfiddle.net/kvn832kh/. I didn't want to tag is JS or C# as the RegEx won't really care.

Comment: Generally yes. But regex has different flavors which is not completely language agnostic.

Comment: @Psidom, I'm realizing that. `Regex.Split(toSplit, @"/\s+([a-z]:+)/");` in C# doesn't work as expected (doesn't split at all). But SO saves the day again - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21922723/regex-works-in-javascript-but-not-in-c-sharp. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Not very familiar with C#. But I think firstly you probably don't need `/`, I tested [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester) with `\s+([a-z]:+)`, it seems to match correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's in javascript, you can use the `split` method, and capture the split pattern that you'd like to keep:

```js
var s = 'foo u:james h c:user p:product'

console.log(
  s.split(/\s+([a-z]:+)/)
)
```