# RegEx behavior not as expected in C#

Tags: c#, regex

**Background**

I have just begun working with RegEx ([last night](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46125515/capture-full-delimiter-with-regex)).

I began matching a single `[singleletter]:` with the expression below:

> **Expression:** \s+([a-z]:+)
>
> **Original string:** foo u:james h c:user p:product
>
> **Output:** ["foo ", "u:", "james h ", "c:", "user ", "p:", "product"]

**Problem**

I'm trying to modify the RegEx to capture `[fullword]:` instead of `[sigleletter]:`. Both expressions below work as desired on [regexr.com](http://regexr.com/), but do not work in C#. What am I doing wrong?

> **Option 1:** [a-zA-Z]*([a-zA-Z]:+)
>
> **Option 2:** \w*([a-zA-Z]:+)
>
> **Test string:** foo user:james h cust:user prod:product
>
> **Desired Output:** ["foo", "user:", "james h ", "cust:", "user ", "prod:", "product"]
>
> **Fullword definition:** case-insensitive a-z (plus the colon)

**C# that doesn't work**

```
var foo1 = Regex.Split("cust:test", "[a-zA-Z]*([a-zA-Z]:+)");
var foo2 = Regex.Split("cust:test", "\w*([a-zA-Z]:+)");
```

Lastly, the first expression that currently works with `[singleletter]:' returns and empty match at the beginning for every string tested, but only in C#. Again, I feel like I'm missing something...

Comment: `Regex.Split("foo u:james h c:user p:product", @"\s+");`

Comment: What is considered to be a *fullword*?

Comment: @L.B, I've updated my question to better describe desired output. Again, this works on regexr.com.

Comment: Put `+` after character class. `\b[a-zA-Z]+:`

Comment: @revo, updated question to define full word

Comment: `var foo1 = Regex.Matches("cust:test:iii", "[a-zA-Z]*([a-zA-Z]:+)");` matches `cust:` and `test:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different engines work differently. You should try word boundary meta-character in addition to a little bit modification:

```
\b([a-zA-Z]+:)
```

Comment: That does it. How frustrating. I'm not sure I quite understand the difference between \w and \b. Time for some more reading. Thanks!